# camera shutter noise sometimes does not play when taking a photo.

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Sometimes when you aggressively start taking pictures in my iOS camera app it sometimes does not play the noise. Why is this? To resolve this I have inserted the following. And now I was going to disable the normal cameras noise to ensure that only one noise is heard. But is this allowed?

```
import AudioToolbox
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1108)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason this is not allowed. I'm assuming you are asking about App Review and if it's allowed to get through that process.

Since it is a [documented and public API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/1405248-audioservicesplaysystemsound) you shouldn't run into any problems with this.

Comment: What about the other part of the question?

Comment: About why it does not play the noise?

Comment: @neburRB Without any detail and no code, I can only guess at this point.

Comment: I understand, Have you ever used snapchat and held teh photo button but let go just before it woudl turn into a photo? when you do so you will notice that you get a weird double shutter noise. What woudl that be caused by. Becasue it seems they have teh same pribplem as me

Comment: @neburRB Could be a problem with the underlying API and lower level stuff of the API that Apple handles. Could be a problem with device performance. Could even be a coding problem with Snapchat. Could also be a threading issue or memory issue. I'm honestly just guessing at this point.